# Android applications and Google Play Store on Chrome OS - Testing Platform

Tags: android, google-play, emulation, google-chrome-os, chromium-os

There is an Android applications and Google Play Store support in official Chrome OS from version 53:
https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7021273?hl=en

**Is there an emulator/testing platform available in addition to official Chromebooks?**

I tried CloudReady from Neverwhere:

> https://www.neverware.com/freedownload

And builds from:

> https://arnoldthebat.co.uk

All these builds are based on version 53 or higher, but none of these support Android Apps/Google Play Store.